# Get utm_source on APP install

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play, app-store, installation

How can I get the utm_source from the app markets (android & ios) and use it in my code?

For example, I want to get the 'stackoverflow' string from thsoe URLs on App Install:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ginra.threechicks2&utm_source=stackoverflow

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/three-chicks-and-friends/id1062989630?ls=1&mt=8&utm_source=stackoverflow

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When It comes to an Android, I think you're looking for `InstallReferer` https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tagmanager/InstallReferrerReceiver. 
I think it's impossible to do that in 'pure' Unity and you'll have to write some native plugins on your own or use existing ones.